# read the value in stdin file descriptor 0 in C

Tags: c, pipe, stdin, file-descriptor

I know that in C the stdin file descriptor is 0. I append file descriptor 0 to the list and use select() to detect if there is any input from console.

It can successfully detect that there is input. But the question is how do I retrieve the value and how? (the code ignored error check)

```
fd_set master;
int console=0; //my stdin file descriptor
fdmax = console + 1;
FD_SET(console,&master); 

select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

for(i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++) {
    if (FD_ISSET(i, &master)){
        printf("input detected!\n");
        dump_line(stdin); //clear the buffer 

        //do w.e here
    }
```

Comment: Just read from fd=0 using read()?

Answer (score 0):

Use `read` from file descriptor `0`.

Careful! Don't use `scanf` since its buffering can interfere with `select`.